# Groupby and difference in Python/R

Tags: python, r, dplyr, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset as follows[image]

I want to groupby Agent column and get the difference between maximum and minimum Resolved time for each Agent (For eg. for Adnan Shaikh the output will come as 01:58:22).

How can I do this in Python/R ??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is `Resolved.time` always monotonic increasing for each agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for python it would be:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "Agent": ["Adnan Shaikh", "Adnan Shaikh", "Adnan Shaikh",
              "Akshay Padaya", "Akshay Padaya", "Akshay Padaya",
              "Akshay Padaya"],
    "Resolved.time": ["2021-07-28 12:11",
                      "2021-07-28 12:23",
                      "2021-07-28 13:06",
                      "2021-07-28 10:44",
                      "2021-07-28 12:45",
                      "2021-07-28 13:05",
                      np.nan]})
df["Resolved.time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Resolved.time"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

result = df.groupby("Agent").agg(
    Resolved_time=("Resolved.time", lambda x: np.max(x) - np.min(x))
).reset_index()
```

Result is like this:

|  | Agent | Resolved_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Adnan Shaikh | 0 days 00:55:00 |
| 1 | Akshay Padaya | 0 days 02:21:00 |

Answer (score 0):

In R, something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(agent = c("Adnan Shaikh", "Adnan Shaikh", "Adnan Shaikh", "Akshay Padaya", "Akshay Padaya", "Akshay Padaya", "Akshay Padaya"),
             Resolved.time =lubridate::ymd_hm(c("2021-07-28 12:11","2021-07-28 12:23", "2021-07-28 13:06", "2021-07-28 10:44", "2021-07-28 12:45", "2021-07-28 13:05", NA)))


df %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  group_by(agent) %>% 
  mutate(result = max(Resolved.time) - min(Resolved.time), result = lubridate::seconds_to_period(result))
```

Gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   agent [2]
  agent         Resolved.time       result   
  <chr>         <dttm>              <Period> 
1 Adnan Shaikh  2021-07-28 12:11:00 55M 0S   
2 Adnan Shaikh  2021-07-28 12:23:00 55M 0S   
3 Adnan Shaikh  2021-07-28 13:06:00 55M 0S   
4 Akshay Padaya 2021-07-28 10:44:00 2H 21M 0S
5 Akshay Padaya 2021-07-28 12:45:00 2H 21M 0S
6 Akshay Padaya 2021-07-28 13:05:00 2H 21M 0S
```